# How to measure execution time of all functions in a process using perf?

Tags: c, function, profiling, perf, time-measurement

I have a project where сalculations are run via a files. I need to measure the execution time of functions that are called after running a certain file. All the functions of the code are located in a large number of other files. Below is the perf probe - method I use to measure the time of a single function. This method is easy to use if you need to measure the time for a small number of functions, but in my case there are a lot of functions in different binares and files and it takes a long time to create probe events for each function.

Create a probe events, for entry and exit points of function:
`sudo perf probe -x ./binary_file_name --add func_name --add func_name%return`

Starting profiling with created events:
`sudo perf record -e probe_binary_file_name:func_name -e probe_binary_file_name:func_name ./a.out`

As a result, I can find out the number of calls of func_name and how long it worked for each call.
Is there any way to create probe events for large number of functions without writing out all their names?

Comment: `-e probe_a_bunch_of_stuff_kk_thx`? I'm pretty sure you'll need to be specific here, but with comments in your code and a script to read those and identify which functions they pertain to, you could somewhat automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. You write a [`perl/python`] script that parses the `.c` files and extracts the function names.
2. If you don't have the source for some files, you can do `readelf -s` on the `.o` and/or `a.out` files and extract the names that are marked `FUNC`.

For the first approach, you could first run the source file through an indenter program (e.g. GNU `indent`). It can force the function's return type onto a separate line and the function name to column 1. This makes the parsing quite easy: any line that begins with the regex `^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)[(]` will be a function name.

This script can be run as part of the `make` and output the names (in *any* format you wish) to an output file. This file could also contain the exact `perf` arguments(s) you want.

Comment: A possibly better way to get probe-able function names is using `perf ` itself: `perf probe --funcs --exec=<executable>`.